# sudo apt-get update fails on postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to install nodejs but it keeps on failing. So I have uninstalled nodejs and found out that sudo apt-get update still fails. It's been so long that I have used postgresql. but here is my error during sudo apt-get update:

```
  Get:41 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en [81.6 kB]                                                        
Err http://apt.postgresql.org precise-pgdg InRelease                                                                                       

Err http://apt.postgresql.org precise-pgdg Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to apt.postgresql.org:80 (2a00:f10:111:50::228). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:f10:111:50::228 80]
Fetched 14.4 MB in 6min 3s (39.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/precise-pgdg/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/precise-pgdg/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to apt.postgresql.org:80 (2a00:f10:111:50::228). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:f10:111:50::228 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

As you can see, the first line succeeded and the rest of updates above it. The error started on the second line. I do not know where else to go. Please help me.
I could not proceed with anything since sudo apt-get update has a problem.

Comment: Not a programming question, possible duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/329450/e-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-ignored-or-old-ones-used

Comment: Oh, i've mixed up stackoverflow and askubuntu. 
I'll ask this on askubuntu. Thanks.
but i don't think this is the same question as that link because that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I have asked this on askubuntu. Sorry for this. Should I delete this post? @spicyramen

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y build-essential

sudo apt-get install curl

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Firstly, <br/>
sudo apt-get update <br/>
 does not work. since it has the problem. I tried to proceed with <br/>
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential<br/>
sudo apt-get install curl<br/>
It is already the newest version.<br/>
<br/>
When I run <br/>
curl -sl https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -<br/>
tries to run apt-get update before proceeding to curl. which means it goes back to the main problem, sudo apt-get update.